# python geopandas TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, ipython, geopandas

Trying to plot something using geopandas and was also trying to do similar mapping using bokeh, but ran into the same error spent too many hours googling and can't seem to fix it.

I'm running on Mac OS X 10.10.5 running ipython notebook (python 2.7.10) in a virtualenv. I've installed ActiveTLC 8.6.4 on the system. I'm stumped

```
import geopandas as gp`
from matplotlib import pyplot

df = gp.read_file('TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.shp')
df.plot()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-4f76bcc16520> in <module>()
----> 1 df.plot()

/Users/thisuser/.virtualenvs/geopandas/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.pyc in plot(self, *args, **kwargs)
    379 
    380     def plot(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 381         return plot_dataframe(self, *args, **kwargs)
    382 
    383 def _dataframe_set_geometry(self, col, drop=False, inplace=False, crs=None):

/Users/thisuser/.virtualenvs/geopandas/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopandas/plotting.pyc in plot_dataframe(s, column, colormap, alpha, categorical, legend, axes, scheme, k)
    178 
    179     if column is None:
--> 180         return plot_series(s.geometry, colormap=colormap, alpha=alpha, axes=axes)
    181     else:
    182         if s[column].dtype is np.dtype('O'):

/Users/thisuser/.virtualenvs/geopandas/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopandas/plotting.pyc in plot_series(s, colormap, alpha, axes)
    103     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    104     if axes == None:
--> 105         fig = plt.gcf()
    106         fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
    107         ax = plt.gca()

/Users/thisuser/.virtualenvs/geopandas/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in gcf()
    576         return figManager.canvas.figure
    577     else:
--> 578         return figure()
    579 
    580 

/Users/thisuser/.virtualenvs/geopandas/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in figure(num, figsize, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, frameon, FigureClass, **kwargs)
    525                                         frameon=frameon,
    526                                         FigureClass=FigureClass,
--> 527                                         **kwargs)
    528 
    529         if figLabel:

/Users/thisuser/.virtualenvs/geopandas/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.pyc in new_figure_manager(num, *args, **kwargs)
     82     FigureClass = kwargs.pop('FigureClass', Figure)
     83     figure = FigureClass(*args, **kwargs)
---> 84     return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
     85 
     86 

/Users/thisuser/.virtualenvs/geopandas/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.pyc in new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
     90     """
     91     _focus = windowing.FocusManager()
---> 92     window = Tk.Tk()
     93     window.withdraw()
     94 

/Users/thisuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.pyc in __init__(self, screenName, baseName, className, useTk, sync, use)
   1812                 baseName = baseName + ext
   1813         interactive = 0
-> 1814         self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
   1815         if useTk:
   1816             self._loadtk()

TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    /opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/lib/tcl8.5 /Users/thisuser/.virtualenvs/geopandas/lib/tcl8.5 /Users/thisuser/.virtualenvs/lib/tcl8.5 /Users/thisuser/.virtualenvs/geopandas/library /Users/thisuser/.virtualenvs/library /Users/thisuser/.virtualenvs/tcl8.5.18/library /Users/thisuser/tcl8.5.18/library



This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

Comment: Did you intend to be using a venv on top of conda?  If you are using conda, you should use their envs.  If you don't think you are using anaconda, then you have your installs crossed.

Comment: Which would partially explain it, as Tcl 8.5 (looked for by anaconda) isn't a Tcl 8.4 as installed by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close this, it was a path issue. I uninstalled anaconda and it seemed to clear things up. Thanks to tcaswell for the tip.